# Hitachi CR210 console command

Tags: maintenance, console-server

I am looking for command for console for Hitachi CR210.

this is the equivalent of HP ILO, where you can connect to ILO IP with ssh, have access to console (if OS is in text mode), issue power off/on hosts, simulate a blade withdrawal and all.

login to host give me the following

```
host:~ # ssh -l user01 8.8.8.8
user01@8.8.8.8's password:
# inactivity_timer[min] : 10
S0051
ALL RIGHTS RESERVED, COPYRIGHT (C), 2011, 2012, HITACHI, LTD.
Chassis ID        : 9 T999999999
Firmware Revision :
$ ?
E0025 : Command is invalid.
S0005 : Command was invalid.
S0000 : Command was finished.
```

I have tried replacing `?` by `h`,`he`,`help`,`info` but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All information is located [here](https://origin-download.hds.com/download/epcra/crh0063.pdf) (annexe B5)

```
host:~ # ssh -l user01 8.8.8.8
user01@8.8.8.8's password:
# inactivity_timer[min] : 10
S0051
ALL RIGHTS RESERVED, COPYRIGHT (C), 2011, 2012, HITACHI, LTD.
Chassis ID        : 9 T999999999
Firmware Revision :
$ show remote-access protocol http
-- HTTP setting --
Port number      : 80
Allow            : allow
S0002 : Command succeeded.
S0000 : Command was finished.
$ show language system
-- System language --
Language : english
S0002 : Command succeeded.
S0000 : Command was finished.
$ show chassis setting
-- chassis setting --
Chassis ID                     : 9 T999999999
Maintenance classification     : normal
-- chassis FRU setting --
Part/model number              : XX-XXXXXXX-XXX-X
Serial number                  : 12345-XXXXXXX-XXX-000000000
Model ID                       : YY
Midplane ID                    : ZZ
First WWN                      : 0000000000000000
S0002 : Command succeeded.
S0000 : Command was finished.​
```

etc
etc
etc